# Access to an object from an Array JSON

Tags: php, xml, json

my problem is that i can't access to a specific object in a JSON array. i followed a lot of solutions but they don't work !!
this is my script:

```
<?php

class XmlToJsonConverter {
    public function ParseXML ($url) {
    $fileContents= file_get_contents($url);
    // Remove tabs, newline, whitespaces in the content array
    $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
    $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
    $myXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
    //--------------
    unset($myXml['@attributes']);
    unset($myXml['channel']);

    //$json = json_encode($myXml['item']);
    //var_dump($myXml);    
    $json = json_encode($myXml);
    $arr = json_decode($json, true);
    echo json_encode($arr['item']);

}
}

//Path of the XML file
$url= 'http://www.lequipe.fr/rss/actu_rss_Football.xml';

//Create object of the class
$jsonObj = new XmlToJsonConverter();

//Pass the xml document to the class function $myjson = 
$myjson = $jsonObj->ParseXMl($url);
//echo ($myjson);

?>
```

this script return null.
i just want to access to 'item' in this array.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line ...

```
echo json_encode($arr['item']);
```

... into this:

```
return json_encode($arr['channel']['item']);
```

Then uncomment your `echo` at the end of the file:

```
$myjson = $jsonObj->ParseXMl($url);
echo $myjson;
```